# Android Studio 4.1 problem with evaluating debugged data

Tags: android, android-studio

Anyone has idea why Android studio is hanging up on evaluating/collecting data in debugger. 
It is nearly impossible to debug anything as in 50% cases I am experiencing such infinite collecting data like on picture below...

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm currently having the same problem. Have you found any solutions?